# Deploy or publish Asp.Net Core 6.0 Web Job Zip file on Azure App service (Window Instance) using AZURE CLI

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-cli, asp.net-core-6.0, azure-webjobs-triggered

I want to Deploy or publish my Asp.Net Core 6.0 Web Job (Continuous) project Zip file on Azure App service (Window Instance) using AZURE CLI

I want it to deploy using AZURE CLI Commends only

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Syntax of Azure CLI for publishing/deploying the Web Job to the Azure App Service**:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release -o .deploy/app_data/Jobs/Continuous/pgp
cp run.cmd .deploy/app_data/Jobs/Continuous/pgp
cd .deploy ; zip -r ../deploy.zip . * ; cd ..
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP -n $AZURE_APP_SERVICE --src ./deploy.zip
```

***From your current working directory location, you have to run these commands.***

**Example**:

**Note**: `run.cmd` file consists of the command called  `dotnet MyWebJob.dll %*`

```
dotnet publish src --configuration Release -o '../_zip/app_data/Jobs/Continuous/MyWebJob'
copy ./run.cmd './_zip/app_data/Jobs/Continuous/MyWebJob'
Compress-Archive -Path ./_zip/* -DestinationPath ./deploy.zip -Force
az webapp deployment source config-zip -g mywebjobapp-rg -n mywebjobapp --src ./deploy.zip
```